# Literal int to void *

Tags: c, casting, void-pointers

Translating [GPOINTER_TO_INT and GINT_TO_POINTER](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.34/glib-Type-Conversion-Macros.html#GINT-TO-POINTER%3aCAPS) to plain C I get:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *fn(void *v)
{
    int *i;

    i = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *i = (int)(long)v;
    return i;
}

int main(void)
{
    int *i = fn((void *)(long)10);

    printf("%d\n", *i);
    free(i);
    return 0;
}
```

Is it portable?

Why the cast to `long`?

In GTK is used for callbacks e.g.:

```
#define FLAG 10

static void panel_set_handler(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
    panel_set(GPOINTER_TO_INT(data));
}

g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(menu_item), "activate", G_CALLBACK(panel_set_handler), GINT_TO_POINTER(FLAG));
```

Comment: Every aspect of this is code is *terrible*. What are you actually trying to achieve? If anything, you can store a void pointer in a `uintptr_t` or `intptr_t`.

Comment: intptr_t(<stdint.h>) better

Comment: *Why the cast to long?* You don't need it. My question is why would you even do something like that?

Comment: @KerrekSB I know is terrible, I'm trying to understand, see edit

Comment: @Armin, guys of glib are casting as you can see in this [link](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.34/glib-Type-Conversion-Macros.html#GINT-TO-POINTER%3aCAPS), why?

Comment: @DavidRF I quess they don't know variadic functions.

Comment: GTK and glib should never be used as a learning tool unless you want to learn how many horrible atrocities of C abuse and bad API design that you can fit into one project. The cast to long because this code will only work on an architecture where `sizeof(long) == sizeof(void *)` and if I recall correctly it shuts up warnings on some gcc version (this is a legitimate trick when writing a VM system in a kernel where you need to perform math on addresses and convert them into pointers later, but completely insane outside of a kernel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution 1: casts

The simplest, Just cast to and from `intptr_t`. It's the correct version of what the GLib macros do.

### Solution 2: using the heap

If you have something bigger than an intptr_t, or when you're not confident in sizes, you can use a dynamically-allocated memory pointer, without casts this time:

```
void* ToHeap(void const *data, size_t dataSize)
{
    void* ret = malloc(dataSize);
    if(ret != NULL)
        memcpy(ret, data, dataSize);
    return ret;
}

int FromHeap(void* heapPtr, void *data, size_t dataSize)
{
    int ret = 0;
    if(heapPtr != NULL)
    {
        memcpy(data, heapPtr, dataSize);
        free(heapPtr);
        ret = 1;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Here is a wrapper for use with `int`s:

```
void* IntToHeap(int i)
{
    return ToHeap(&i, sizeof(int));
}
int IntFromHeap(void*heapPtr, int defaultValue)
{
    int ret;
    if(!FromHeap(heapPtr, &ret, sizeof(int))
        ret = defaultValue;
    return ret;
}
```

And you can use this that way:

```
#define FLAG 10

static void panel_set_handler(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
    panel_set(IntFromHeap(data, 0));
}

g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(menu_item), "activate", G_CALLBACK(panel_set_handler), IntToHeap(FLAG));
```

That way is a bit like your post, minus all these casts.

Comment: +1, but I don't want an alternative, I want to know if this code is portable and the reason to cast (int)(long)

Comment: With the cast using (long), I'd say it's not portable. Under the LLP64 model, pointers are bigger than longs. I also don't see why `fn` would take a parameter one way (casting) and return it via dynamic allocation.

Comment: Thank you Medinoc, no reason in this case, in GTK the reason is get params and set results as `void *` through callbacks

Comment: I edited my post for cases when you really want/need to use the heap. But without casts this time (so, you either use the heap, *or* casts).